# add new menu items after existing items

Tags: 8, navigation

When I create a page and add a menu link, it appears above the existing menu items (in the menu tree). Can this be changed so that new items flow under existing items?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you selecting the right part of the tree?

Comment: I mean that drupal automatically gives a weight of 0 to the menu items and they appear on top of items previously created. I want that they appear below - with greater weight as jBlobsmith points out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You have to change the "Weight". If you put a weight greater than the other menu links, the last will appear below.

Comment: Ah yes, now I understand why it is happening, now the question is, how to adjust it so that new items automatically get a greater weight.